# cannot open file as first argument

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am trying to run a script like :

`./script.sh file`

but I am receiving ( if I use a txt file ):

```
=:        cannot open `=' (No such file or directory)
test.txt: ASCII text
Second
```

If I use a gz file:

```
=:           cannot open `=' (No such file or directory)
test.txt.gz: gzip compressed data, was "test.txt", last modified: Wed Jul 20 09:17:58 2016, from Unix
Second
```

( I have the script and the file in the same directory )

script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file = $1

if [[ $file == *.gz ]];then

    echo "First"
else
    echo "Second"

fi
```

Comment: @Rahul irrelevant. The problem is spaces around `=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
file = $1
```

runs the `file` command with `=` as the first argument and the result of the split+glob operator applied to the script's first parameter as the remaining arguments.

Variable assignments in Bourne-like shells (like `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `ash`/`dash`, `yash`) are with **no** spaces around the `=` sign:

```
file=$1
```

`file = $1` would be valid as an assignment in `rc`, `es` or `akanga` shells. `csh` and `tcsh` have yet another syntax: `set file = $1:q` and `fish` uses `set file $argv[1]`.